# How to echo single string values from mysql database separately?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to separate single string values?

This is the string in the database: Small:4,Medium:2,Large:5,X-Large:4

I want to echo the sizes and quantity separately. For example I have 2 column table Sizes and Quantity.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Sizes</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?=“echo sizes here";?></td>
        <td><?=“echo quantity here";?></td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
```

So how can I echo sizes and quantity separately from a single string in the database??

Comment: Are you wanting to convert a string to array?

Comment: In php you have `explode` and `substr`. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the string in the database: Small:4,Medium:2,Large:5,X-Large:4

Well, this is not how you use the database efficiently.
You are using a database, then please use the power & convenience of storing data in rows and columns.
Make 2 tables with attributes `(product_ID,size_ID,quantity)` and `(size_ID, size)` and do mapping using `size_ID` attribute.

If you still wish to do it with the given string in your database, you can use something like:

**ALGO printXYZ:**

```
    Scan the string and keep appending characters to an array.  
    if char = ':', print the characters scanned till now and empty/deallocate the array.  
    Then print the next character and stop at char=','.
```

Now you see how inefficient and ugly it is?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to echo the sizes and quantity separately.

You have to **store them separately** in the first place.

Change your database structure by adding another table with all the size types and one cross table with `product id`, `size id` and quantity.

And then just select all the rows from this table that belong to particular product.